# Education is both teaching of skills and knowledge and building a good manner, behaviour and virtues

Tags: word-meaning

In German we have two words:
Erziehung - which means to raise somebody to be of good manner, to have values and virtues and to behave fittingly in one's social environment

and

Bildung - which are academic, intellectual skills, knowledge or practical, handcraft capabilities.

In English I found: education. teaching. upbringing, or to raise a child and parenting.

In English texts I often find that education is used for both “Erziehung“ and “Bildung“. Seems as in English “education“ is both, manners and skills.
This is more a question for educational professionals then for all-day language use.

Am I correct? Maybe this is a bit of hairsplitting, but in German it makes a difference if you are an “Erzieher“ (Erziehung) or a “Lehrer“ (Bildung). Maybe it is educator and teacher in English. But is “Education“ actually used for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While education may be used to describe both contexts in some texts as you have mentioned, *Erziehung* is best translated as *upbringing* in English, and *Bildung* as *education* (in an academic setting).

If one refers to *upbringing* it is usually only about how someone was raised, their values, virtues and behaviours. And when one refers to *education*, unless a specific context is provided then it is assumed to be related to their academic learning.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to see what your question is exactly. Yes, ***education*** is used similarly for academics and for life, although it's more common to use ***education*** to describe academics.

It's very common to ***learn about life*** from parents or teachers. Another common phrase is to ***learn life lessons*** or to ***learn lessons about life.***

When it comes to ***manners***, a parent will tell a child to ***mind your manners***, usually around the dinner table or in front of guests.

When talking about a person's background, you can say that the person had a ***good upbringing*** or a ***bad upbringing***. You can also say the person was ***raised well***.

Although you can say that someone has had a ***good education in life***, it's less common than the phrases described above. More often than not, ***education*** refers to academics. But when used to describe life/mannerisms/upbringing, ***education*** suggests the long and complex process of growing into an adult.